# Proof of summation formula

Tags: proof-verification, summation

I'm trying to help my son with his A level maths. He has the following problem:

i) Prove: $$\sum_{r=1}^n \{(r+1)^3 - r^3\} = (n + 1)^3 - 1$$

ii) Prove: $$(r + 1)^3 - r^3 = 3r^2 + 3r + 1$$

iii) Given these proofs and $\sum_1^n = \frac 1 2 n(n + 1)$ prove:

$$3 \sum_{r=1}^n r^2 = \frac 1 2 n(n + 1)(2n + 1)$$

He managed the first two with no difficulty but is stuck on the third part. I've tried substituting (ii) into (i) but I can't see how that helps. I'm hoping someone can give me some pointers on how to proceed. Would the method of differences help?

Comment: Sum both sides of (ii) from $r=1$ to $n$, then use (i) to simplify the LHS, and the formula given in (iii) for the RHS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have, $$3\sum_{r=1}^nr^2+3\sum_{r=1}^nr+\sum_{r=1}^n1=(n+1)^3-n^3+[n^3-(n-1)^3]+(3^3-2^3)+(2^3-1^3)$$

Observe that the second part the previous term is cancelled by the first part of the next, except for the two terminal termss

$$3\sum_{r=1}^nr^2+3\cdot\frac{n(n+1)}2+n=(n+1)^3-1$$

Can you simplify from here

Comment: Yes - that helps a lot thank you.